# No output from Raven.Client.MvcIntegration.RavenProfiler

Tags: profiling, ravendb

I am having no joy with the RavenDb profiler. There's output rendered in the browser, but the profiler always claims there are no requests and no sessions.

[image]

When the document store is created I make the following call:

```
RavenProfiler.InitializeFor(docStore);
```

And in my master layout I have this, just before the closing body tag:

```
@Raven.Client.MvcIntegration.RavenProfiler.CurrentRequestSessions()
```

As far as I can tell there's nothing more required in order for this to work (of course, I may be wrong) yet the output of the profiler is always as above.

I'm using version 3.0.0.0 of Raven.Client.MvcIntegration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was an issue with how I resolved the DocumentStore via my Windsor Container. It turned out that I ended up with two instances of the DocumentStore, and the wrong one was registered with RavenProfiler. Once I ensured that only one DocumentStore was created, everything started working as expected.